# Cloned Server Cannot connect to SQL Server 2017 Instance

Tags: sql

I just recently cloned a dev server from a production Microsoft Dynamics 365 server having SQL Server 2017 installed on it. Now when I log in to the dev Server and to SQL Server via the SSMS I am getting the following error.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Please let me know where I can change the server information to get the SQL Server get going.

Thanks,

Zahid

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting to the database by IP address rather than by name?

Try connecting to the database directly rather than through SSMS, the link below is from Trend Micro’s website, but it is equally applicable for connecting to any SQL Server database.

[Test the connection to SQL Server](https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1117712-creating-a-data-link-udl-file-and-testing-the-connectivity-to-a-microsoft-sql-server)

Have you double-checked the password is correct? Try typing the password into Notepad to check you haven’t got anything weird going on. I once had a keyboard in a VM set to US when it should have been UK. What I thought was a speech mark was actually the @ symbol. Typing the password in Notepad revealed the issue.

I am 99% certain I had the error message you reported when I tried to connect to SSMS as user SA on DB server A when the password I was entering was actually for DB server B (both servers were on the same subnet). I remember thinking it was odd that I received that error message rather than being told I had entered an incorrect username/password.